# How to connect Jetpack to Wordpress.org when the database URL does not have a "." (i.e. how to disable dev_mode_"

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I am an absolute beginner. I am not even aware of some of the terms.

So basically I am using Wordpress.org to build a website on my Mac. Everything works just fine. However, I would like to connect my desktop Wordpress app and on my Android. The apps request me to connect with Wordpress.com account, so I read that I have to activate Jetpack. When I activate Jetpack on Wordpress.org, it is in development mode because of a missing "dot" in my URL localhost:8888/database

So what is the easiest thing to do? 
- Change my database name to something like database.something
- Create a new database?

I am not sure how to do both the above options.

I tried to change database name from "operations" in phpmyadmin, but it only changes the database on phpmyadmin and gives me an error when I try to load it.

Comment: zelahham, Sorry, I am a little confused. Are you using wordpress.com or building your own site and referencing wordpress.org?

Comment: I am using Wordpress.org to build the website

I want to connect the Mac app and android app to edit the site.

The app is asking me to either login Wordpress.com or sign in a local website by connecting jetpack to my Wordpress.org

Then when I go connect jetpack to Wordpress.org, it says that it can't connect because my website has to be live like www.example.com

But I just want to edit a localhost database....